# Forcefully Import configuration for the eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

This issues is about organise imports.When I do organise imports eclipse automatically imports all the required classes.But it give message "User Intereaction Required" where it get reference from more than one package.

I want to configure eclispse so that it should import forcefully all the  required classes from specified package only.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your import suggestions are based on the libraries which are available under the Build Path of your eclipse project configuration.

If you are using Maven or any other build tool which has integration with eclipse Build Path configuration as a part of the dependency management you need to alter their configurations too.